# Large imagens o Masonry plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I need to create a Mansonry with images. But the images are quite large and I want her to stay with a maximum of 30% of the screen width and height proportionally.
How do these sites to do this (Flickr, pinterest ...) at the time of upload makes several uploads of various sizes, resize the html or javascript etc ....
Anyway, what better way to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: What is a "masonry"?  In English that is a term related to building construction.

Comment: @JimGarrison, It's a pretty common term for tight layouts of block-like items.  http://masonry.desandro.com/ http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, most of these images are re-sized server-side.  You don't want to be sending 100MB of images for your page.  If your layout is flexible in size, then re-size them down to something close to the larger sizes you want, and let the browser scale from there.

Comment: Thank you.
But I realized that the picture changes size according to the resolution that we are seeing and do it in HTML. It's some javascript that creates images of different sizes?
Thank you.